# Problem when loading large json file with d3.js v4

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

When I try to load a small json file with d3.json (d3.js v4), I load it with no problem. However, when I try to load a larger file with 5,036 entries, it looks like the file is only partially loading which messes up my axes in the scatter plot that is generated downstream.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>-->

    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
//d3.json("test_json_small.json", function(error, json) {
d3.json("test_json_large.json", function(error, json) {
    if (error) return console.warn(error);

    curr_data = json.nodes;
    console.log(d3.max(json.nodes, function (d) { return d.posx; }));
    console.log(d3.max(json.nodes, function (d) { return d.posy; }));
    console.log(d3.min(json.nodes, function (d) { return d.posx; }));
    console.log(d3.min(json.nodes, function (d) { return d.posy; }));

});
//Downstream code to generate axis, plot, data, etc.
/*
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
*/

</script>
</html>
```

When I specify a small json file of 10 elements, I get the following output in the console (which is what I expect):

```
26.4137007365
9.91588072476
-17.2945742046
-0.222771036376
```

However, when loading the full json file, the max and min values do not make sense:

```
9.9872339424
9.99461717677
-0.00210396968253
-0.00282843924648
```

In consequence, my axes range are not what they should be. I did not show the results of the plot, but axes effectively range from 0 to 10. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `posx` and `posy` are numbers? `d3.min()` and `d3.max()` use natural order rather than numeric order and your values look pretty much like what you would expect of naturally ordered strings.

Comment: Well strictly speaking, they are stored as strings in the json file: 
...
 "posx": "26.4137007365",
 "posy": "0.283611238262",
... But why would it return correct values with the small json file?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, this will make them strings once parsed to the `json` object which is the reason you get the error. Converting to a number by prefixing it with a unary `+` will cure this problem: `d3.max(json.nodes, function (d) { return +d.posx; })`.

Comment: It works - many, many thanks! I've literally spent hours trying to solve this. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted answer. Cheers!

Comment: For a small amount of data this might seem to work fine, but it is rather a coincidence since in some case natural order is the same as numeric order: "2" < "3". In other cases this won't work, though: "20" < "3". In a large file you are just more likely to encounter values of the second type.